# What is this "it"?

Tags: pronouns, dummy-pronouns

> He usually works for so long as he feels **it** necessary to perfect  his task.

I found this in an exercise book.
What is this "it"? Is it correct?
It means "He works until he can say, "I'm satisfied!"?

Answer (score 1):

The "it" is a dummy pronoun. It is OK. But it is not necessary.   Your paraphrase is accurate.

In my dialect, "so long as" means "provided" (in the conditional sense):

**Yes, you may go to the matinee, *so long as* you bring the car back by 4PM, because I need to use it then myself.**

We would replace "so" with "as":

**He usually works for as long as he feels necessary to perfect his task.**

Comment: "necessary (to work)" is the meaning whether dummy "it" is used, or not.  You can think of the dummy pronoun as a convenient place to attach the adjective "necessary".   The verb *feels* might be paraphrased "feels (to be)" and it functions might like predicate "is".  In English we do not ask "Is necessary?" but instead "Is *it* necessary?", wanting there to be a nominal element to which the predicate adjective can be attached.